# Kentico Repeater Selected Item Transformation

Tags: kentico

I'm having an issues with two repeaters, both using the same Selected Item Transformation. Each repeater is fed by a separate Page Data Source, since i also have pagination.

When an item from repeater 1 is selected, i see the memo data, but also repeater 1 table header, and all of repeater 2's table. Is it possible to set up a new page template for this, and have the memo detail show there?

Here is the memo landing page:
[image: Memo Landing]
And here is the detail page:
[image: Memo Detail]

Here's the tranformation code:

```html
<section id="memoDetail">
  <h1>Memorandum</h1>
  <ul id="memoHeader">
    <li><span class="headerLabel">To:</span> {% To %}</li>
    <li><span class="headerLabel">From:</span> {% From %}</li>
    <li><span class="headerLabel">Subject:</span> {% Subject %}</li>
    <li><span class="headerLabel">Date:</span> {% Date %}</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="memoDetails">{% Details %}</div>
</section>
```

Comment: What does your transformation code look like?  Also, I think you've told us the problem, but I'm not sure you've told us what your desired effect is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're using the same page template for items listing as well as details pages. The answer is yes, you can have different templates for those pages. You'll have to update each page shown in the repeater with new template in this case.
However this is not necessary: you may try to hide second repeater, e.g. base on page type, if repeaters show pages of different type, or put some visibility macro there.
I'm not sure why does header shows up on the second screenshot - there should be something wrong with repeater setting.

Comment: I could set up a memo detail template easy enough, but how i set the repeater and the new template?

Comment: @MarkHandy I'm sorry, I'm totally misunderstood, what you mean under 'new page template'. So you mean 'create new item' page template, correct? Have you considered user contribution web part?

Comment: I originaly based this on the News example from the Corp Site, and all was working, until the requirements changed to show memos for a different role.

I may look at splitting the types to different pages, rather than all on one page

Comment: @MarkHandy I believe, that would make your live easier!

Comment: As do I. I know i had this working. Should also make it easier to maintain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mark, there is a way to force all the content for a page type to be display using a dedicated template. Go to Page Types app > select the page type > General > New page settings > Default page template, and set it there. This way, it doesn't matter where the items are listed by whatever repeaters, they will be displayed with the same template.

Comment: this will change what see on the Form tab for the page, but will not affect live site.

Comment: It does affect the live site, but you will need to make sure the page is using this template when it's created, and in the template property, change the page nesting setting to "Only the nearest master page" instead of "All ancestor pages".

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood your answer. Yes, you're right - you can configure a default page template per page type. But Mark was looking for a "create item/page" form.

Comment: Isn't he looking for a special display template for page items that may be listed by different repeater? If I understand him correctly from the initial question.